# Symfony 3: Deprecated ArrayKeyChoiceList in Form Builder

Tags: php, symfony

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I need some help on this issue I'm trying to get my code compatible with Symfony 3+, originally I was on 2.7.

---

The Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ArrayKeyChoiceList class is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0. Use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ArrayChoiceList instead

---

Below is the code I'm using, basically I'm assembling a simple key value pair in an Array and passing it to choices. I've tried a number of different techniques and looked at various examples and can't get rid of this deprecated warning. Any help would be appreciated!

// src/Forms/Type/LinkType.php

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
  $builder
          ->add('id', TextType::class, array('label' => 'ID for Link', 'required' => false))
          ->add('artistid', HiddenType::class, array('label' => 'Artist ID'))
          ->add('linktypeid', ChoiceType::class,
               array('choices' => $this->fillLinkTypes(),
                     'choice_translation_domain' => false,
                     'label' => 'Link Type')) 
          ->add('url', TextType::class, array('label' => 'URL'))
          ->add('Submit', SubmitType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')))
      ;
  }

  private function fillLinkTypes() {
      $er = $this->em->getRepository('testArtistBundle:LinkTypes');

      $results = $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->orderBy('e.name', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

  $linkTypes = array();
  foreach($results as $lt){
      $linkTypes[$lt->getId()]=$lt->getName();
  }
  return $linkTypes;
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
  {
      $resolver->setDefaults(array(
          'data_class' => 'test\ArtistBundle\Entity\ArtistsLinks',
      ));
  }
```

Comment: Is it this line: `'choices' => $this->fillLinkTypes()` that's causing the error? Can you please verify if that's the case?

Comment: @AlvinBunk that is indeed the line that is causing the issue. If I comment it out, the warning goes away. I've also hardcoded something like this array('1' => 'Test', '2' => 'Another Test) instead of the method with no luck.

Comment: Question: If you are using prod environment, are you clearing cache with `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` everytime you make a change?

Comment: So '1' => works, is fillLinkTypes returning 0 => or '0'.  Makes a difference.  And actually, keys and values are swapped in 2.8 forms.  Maybe update your question with the first few entries of fillLinkTypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Cerad is correct about the swapping of keys/values. I think also, you might need to do this in your `fillLinkTypes` function:

```
foreach($results as $lt){]
    $linkTypes["'" . $lt->getName() . "'"] = "'" . $lt->getId() . "'";
}
```

So that there is a single quote (') around each value/key. Can you try that and see if it works? I'm not certain though but try it.